# General linux question: What is the best way to add another distro to a dual booting system?

Tags: partitioning, dual-boot

I'm currently running a bare bones windows xp install and Ubuntu. Ubuntu being the primary OS. I am wanting to add a 3rd OS that is another linux distro JoliOS. Currently I have 2 partitions 16G for windows, 90 something for ubuntu. I'm assuming I will have to edit the Ubuntu partition to add JoliOS, but how will this affect my boot and is it even possible to run 2 linux OS's off the same partition?

Comment: General Linux questions go here http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This looks like it might help you http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/05/31/how-to-triple-boot-fedora-15-ubuntu-11-04-and-windows-7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Back up everything just to be sure.
2. Shrink your partitions to free some unpartitioned space on the drive.  This can be done from an Ubuntu Live CD using "gparted".  In your case you should be able to just shrink the larger partition.
3. Run the installer for the other distro.  When asked where you would like to install, choose the unpartitioned space.  This *may* involve setting up new partitions manually. When the installer asks if you want to install Grub to the master boot record of your drive, tell it not to (if you are given that option).  It should reboot, but into your existing boot manager.
4. Boot into your existing Linux install (Ubuntu).  Run `sudo update-grub` and Grub should detect the new OS as another secondary OS and add it to the Grub menu.
5. Reboot and the new OS should be in the Grub menu.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was worried about dealing with grub. I'm pretty new to linux in general, any good starting points to learn commands and in and outs? I learned dos and amiga dos in no time back in the day, It would be nice to get to that proficiency with linux.